# Opencv Shape Match

Tags: c++, opencv, match, shapes

I have an image that have many similar patterns and I want to create template use the pattern from the image and use the template that matches the other pattern. I am done using `Halcon` and I want to use `OpenCV` to achieve this. The image is as follows.
Halcon Achieve：

> Halcon Src

```
*shape model
read_image (Image, 'C:/Users/Jason/Documents/ShareWM/image/21.jpg')
rgb1_to_gray (Image, GrayImage1)
gen_rectangle1 (Rectangle, 1428.04, 3185.44, 1811.68, 3967.26)
reduce_domain (Image, Rectangle, ImageReduced)

rgb1_to_gray (ImageReduced, GrayImage)
derivate_gauss (GrayImage, DerivGauss, 2, 'eigenvalue1')
threshold (DerivGauss, Regions, -1.556, 0.266)
connection (Regions, Connection)

select_shape (Connection, SelectedRegions, ['area','circularity'], 'and', [13000,0.3], [9999900,0.4])

union1 (SelectedRegions, RegionUnion)
fill_up (RegionUnion, RegionFillUp)
closing_circle (RegionFillUp, RegionClosing, 5.5)
fill_up (RegionClosing, RegionFillUp1)
boundary (RegionFillUp1, RegionBorder, 'inner')
gen_contour_region_xld (RegionBorder, Contours, 'border')
gen_polygons_xld (Contours, Polygons, 'ramer', 2)

*shape match
create_shape_model_xld (Contours, 2, 0, rad(200), rad(2), 'point_reduction_low', 'ignore_local_polarity', 5, ModelID)

find_shape_model (GrayImage1, ModelID, 0, rad(200), 0.4, 0, 0.5, 'least_squares', 2, 0.9, Row1, Column1, Angle1, Score1)

Num := |Row1|

for Index := 0 to Num-1 by 1
     get_shape_model_contours (ModelContours, ModelID, 1) 
     
     vector_angle_to_rigid (0, 0, 0, Row1[Index], Column1[Index], Angle1[Index], HomMat2D) 
     
     affine_trans_contour_xld (ModelContours, ContoursAffinTrans, HomMat2D) 
endfor

clear_shape_model (ModelID)
```

> end src

[image]

Comment: HOW did you solve it in halcon?

Comment: Halcon source code has been uploaded